# script in bash with string

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a complete list of names separated by commas:

```
second_surnameA first_surnameA, nameA second_surnameB first_surnameB, nameB second_surnameC first_surnameC, nameC ....
```

So I'm trying to capture with a bash script the name of all persons (A, B, C) in each file:

```
  second_surnameA first_surnameA, nameA

  second_surnameB first_surnameB, nameB

  second_surnameC first_surnameC, nameC
```

I executed:

```
cat names_file.txt | tr ',' '\n'
```

is almost what I need but not enouth. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU` sed:

```sh
sed -re 's/(\S+ +){3}/&\n/g' input_file | sed 's/ $//' > output_file
```

The pattern `(\S+ +){3}` matches three times `{3}` a group made of: one or more non-spaces `\S+` followed by one or more spaces. The replacement string `&\n` appends a new line to each matched pattern. The second sed removes trailing spaces and writes to `output_file`

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i=i+3) print $i,$(i+1),$(i+2)}' inputfile
```

It simply uses blank spaces as delimiters to each field and prints three of them for each line.